# Return statement not changing variable on global scope

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am writing a calculator program with a user interface similar to a real calculator. Everything had been going fine (unusual for me xD) until I needed to have multiple values returned from one function (I read on another post that this can be done with an array). I haven't been returning the values to any specific place so I think they are just being sent out to the global scope, and this has worked so far with other functions like `updateDisplay()`. However, when I try to return `returnValue` from `operationClick()`, it doesn't send the changes outside of the function.

Here are some bits and pieces of my code (hopefully enough so you can find what I'm doing wrong):

```
returnValue = [false, undefined];
numberArray = new Array;

function operationClick(operation, concat, returnValue) {
    if (operation == "equals") {
        concatComplete = returnValue[1] + concat;
        $('.screen_text').html(Number(concatComplete));
    }
    else if (operation == "add") {
        returnValue = [true, concat + "+"];
        console.log(returnValue); // The new value is correct here but not anywhere else :(
    }
    return returnValue; // Something goes wrong here!
}

function updateDisplay(array) {
    concat = array.join("");
    $('.screen_text').html(concat);
    return concat
}

function numberClick(number, returnValue) {
    if (returnValue[0] == true) {
        // This should run once operationClick() else if statement runs but it doesn't
        numberArray = new Array;
        $('.screen_text').html("");
    }
    numberArray.push(number);
    updateDisplay(numberArray);
    return numberArray;
}

$('.button_1').click(function(){
    numberClick(1, returnValue);
});

$('.button_addition').click(function(){
    operationClick("add", concat);
})

$('.button_equals').click(function(){
    operationClick("equals", concat, returnValue);
})
```

Thank you in advance for your help. It is greatly appreciated! I hope my code isn't too messy.

Comment: `return` doesn't create or alter global variables. It just returns the value from the function. You still need to explicitly *assign* that value to a variable.

Comment: I thought so too, but I don’t understand why returning numberArray and concat in the same way works

Comment: `push` *mutates* an existing object. Since the object only exists once, that change will be seen by anyone who holds a reference to it.

Comment: Sorry I’m having a hard time understanding this. If numberArray only exists once why can I keep appending values to the same array after the function finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, returning a value doesn't automatically update anything, you need to do something with the returned value in the caller. If you want to replace the `returnValue` global variable with the new value, do it with an assignment.

```
$('.button_addition').click(function(){
    returnValue = operationClick("add", concat);
});
```

This doesn't happen in the `operationClick()` function itself because it has declared a local variable named `returnValue` (function parameters are automatically made local variables), and this shadows the global variable. You could also solve the problem simply by giving the function parameter a different name.

```
function operationClick(operation, concat, oldReturnValue) {
    if (operation == "equals") {
        concatComplete = oldReturnValue[1] + concat;
        $('.screen_text').html(Number(concatComplete));
    }
    else if (operation == "add") {
        returnValue = [true, concat + "+"];
        console.log(returnValue); // The new value is correct here but not anywhere else :(
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the the parameter name as you suggested and suddenly, _like magic_, the program is now working! Was it just the naming conflict that messed things up?

Comment: Yes, that's what was messing it up.